# SAS VA (SAASNOW) - Filter AND condition cross rows

Tags: filter, sas

Im trying to find all companies with two products. My issue is when I make a filter, it only looks on one row at the time, so Product=car AND Product=dog could never be true, because each row only have one product.

[image: SASVA]

I cant make it look across the 'name' column with the AND operator.

```
+------+-----------------+
| name | productniveau_2 |
+------+-----------------+
| IKEA | car             |
| IKEA | dog             |
| SAS  | house           |
+------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Rasmus,
To get just the companies with 2 products, you can do a Proc SQL grouping to get all that have that criteria.

```
  data have;
    input Company $4. Product $10.;
    cards;
    IKEA    A24
    IKEA    A53
    IKEA    A67
    Sear    A35
    Sear    A86
    Sear    A24
    DDDD    A35
    DDDD    A56
    AAAA    A21
    ;
    run;


        proc Sql;
        create table wante as
             select Company, count(Company) as Count

             from have
              group by Company
              having count(Product) = 2; 
        quit;

    /*having count(Product) > 1 will get you all companies that have more than one product */
```

[image]

If you need to have the company and product listed, you can use a subquery like below...

```
data have;
input Company $4. Product $10.;
cards;
IKEA    A24
IKEA    A53
IKEA    A67
Sear    A35
Sear    A86
DDDD    A35
DDDD    A56
AAAA    A21
;
run;



proc Sql;
create table want as
     select Company, Product

     from have
      where company in ( select Company

             from have
              group by Company
              having count(Company) = 2);
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i havnt done Proc SQL before in SAS VA, but i will try this solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you can build 2 measures based on Product category: hasCar and hasDog whith definition like this:

[image]

Next create aggregate measure 'want':

[image]

In last step put filter on the object where want = 1:

[image]

Comment: Ahh that makes sense so by multiplying all the "if exists", you can show all that have a value of 1.

Comment: Hmm I cant use it as a filter in the view, only as a measure on my Y-axis

Comment: What do you mean, that you can't use it as a filter in the view? You can't use aggregate measures in advance filters. But on the right panel in filter section you can choose aggr mes froma the list next to 'Add Filter' button, and choose value 1 from slider.